# Populate multiple collections on same type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to populate a Product object which contains two collections. 
The current code works fine and populates the Product.GraphicItems collection, but I also need to populate the Product.InfoItems collection, but I can't figure out the syntax for multiple collections.

**Current select**:

```
var result = await this.Context.ShopCategorys
    .Include(cat => cat.InfoItems)
    .Include(cat => cat.Products)
        .ThenInclude(prd => prd.GraphicItems)
            .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Graphic)
                .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Items)
    .SingleAsync(cat => cat.Id.Equals(id));
```

**Product.cs**:

```
[Table("ShopProduct")]
public class Product : BaseShop
{
    public bool Active { get; set; } = true;
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int CultureId { get; set; } = -1;
    public List<ProductInfo> InfoItems { get; set; } = new List<ProductInfo>();
    public List<ProductGraphic> GraphicItems { get; set; } = new List<ProductGraphic>();
}
```

**ProductInfo.cs**:

```
[Table("ShopProductInfo")]
public class ProductInfo : BaseShop, IInfoItem
{
    public int? ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CultureId { get; set; }
    public Culture Culture { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
var result = await this.Context.ShopCategorys
    .Include(cat => cat.InfoItems)
    .Include(cat => cat.Products)
        .ThenInclude(prd => prd.InfoItems)
    .Include(cat => cat.Products)
        .ThenInclude(prd => prd.GraphicItems)
            .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Graphic)
                .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Items)
    .SingleAsync(cat => cat.Id.Equals(id));
```